# How to recreate the grid (in screenshot) in SwiftUI without breaking navigation?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to recreate a layout similar to the Reminders app. Looking at it makes me think it was built with SwiftUI. I also believe Apple mentioned so in one of the WWDC videos (can't remember which one).

[image: Screenshot and explanation of problems]

This above screenshot seems to be a `List`, with a `LazyVGrid` as the first `View` inside the `List`. Tapping on each of the items in the `LazyVGrid`, such as *Today*, *Scheduled*, *All* and *Flagged*, navigates to the relevant screen, which means they are all `NavigationLink`s. Also note that the `LazyVGrid` has 2 columns.

And then there is another section "My Lists" which has rows which look like regular list rows in a `List` with style `.insetGrouped`. Also, every item in this `Section` is a `NavigationItem`, and thus comes with the disclosure indicator on the right as usual. Recreating this is trivial, so it has been left out from the MRE.

I am having trouble recreating the first section, which has that LazyVGrid. I faced 3 problems (as mentioned in the image), of which I have been able to solve the first one only. The other two problems remain. I want to know if this MRE can be fixed, or is my entire approach incorrect.

I am including a minimum reproducible example below.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RemindersView()
        }
    }
}

struct RemindersView: View {
    
    private var columns: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))]
    private var smartLists: [SmartList] = SmartList.sampleLists
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Using LazyVGrid")) {
                    grid
                }
                Section(header: Text("Using HStack")) {
                    hstack
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Store")
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
    
    private var grid: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(smartLists) { smartList in
                // This use of **ZStack with an EmptyView with opacity 0** is a hack being used to avoid the disclosure indicator on each item in the grid
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    NavigationLink( destination: SmartListView(list: smartList)) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    .opacity(0)
                    SmartListView(list: smartList)
                }
            }
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    }
    
    private var hstack: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(smartLists) { smartList in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SmartListView(list: smartList)) {
                        SmartListView(list: smartList)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                }
            }
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    }
}

struct RemindersView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RemindersView()
    }
}

struct SmartList: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: String
    var count: Int
    var icon: String
    var iconColor: Color
    
    static var sampleLists: [SmartList] {
        let today = SmartList(title: "Today", count: 5, icon: "20.circle.fill", iconColor: .blue)
        let scheduled = SmartList(title: "Scheduled", count: 12, icon: "calendar.circle.fill", iconColor: .red)
        let all = SmartList(title: "All", count: 77, icon: "tray.circle.fill", iconColor: .gray)
        let flagged = SmartList(title: "Flagged", count: 5, icon: "flag.circle.fill", iconColor: .orange)
        return [today, scheduled, all, flagged]
    }
}

struct SmartListView: View {
    var list: SmartList
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(systemName: list.icon)
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(list.iconColor)
                
                Spacer()
                Text("\(list.count)")
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            }
            Text(list.title)
                .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.25))
        )
        .padding(2)
        .frame(minWidth: 150)
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: Adding video demo of what editing the dynamic Grid looks like and how the Grid has dynamic grid items (via the Edit button at the top right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0koux.jpg

Comment: I don't see any sense to use LazyVGrid for 4 always visible static items, I'd use VStack+2xHStack. Also you don't need to put those 4 items into List.

Comment: The items in that Grid can be changed dynamically by the user via the Edit button at the top right. Specially when you enable an odd number of views, then the last item becomes full width. Here's a video demo of it: https://imgur.com/a/TV0kifY. So is there any way your approach will work for something non-static?

Also putting the grid outside the List messes the View and the NavigationLinks do not work. You can try the self-contained MRE. If you are able to make <navigating to the detail views and then back> work, then please let me know the changes that make it possible.

Comment: @Asperi I have added a screen recording to the post. Also see my above comment.